# Old PIC16F84A program

Tags: assembly, pic

I don't have any programming experience and I desperately need to make this work, my father passed away recently and he was the one that coded at our family company, please help!

I need to add a delay for this program before the routine of "PROX_ETIQ" wich controls a stepping motor, this is an old program that was changed many times and have a lot of disabled functions in it. I need it to wait 1 sec before moving the stepping motor.

```
;*************************************************
;       PROGRAMA PARA ETIQUETADORA LASER
;
;       CLIENTE : OPERACIONAL
;       MODELO  : 
;       PLACA(S): PCI-1
#DEFINE VERSAO   "JLE V1.0"      
;       DATA    : 01/04/09
;*************************************************
;   LIST P=PIC16C84
   LIST P=PIC16F84
;        LIST P=PIC16F84A


;   INCLUDE "P16C84.INC"
    INCLUDE "P16F84.INC"
;   INCLUDE "P16F84A.INC"
    __CONFIG (_CP_ON & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _HS_OSC)



IPORTA          EQU B'00011101'
PPORTA          EQU B'00011100'
IPORTB          EQU B'00001111'
PPORTB          EQU B'00001111'
POPTION         EQU B'00000100'
PINTCON         EQU B'10110000'

;*************************************************
;       DEFINICAO DE CONTANTES
;*************************************************

CLOCK           EQU .16000000   ;original .16000000
PRESCALER       EQU .32
FCLOCK          EQU CLOCK/4/PRESCALER
FINT            EQU .1000       ;1ms = 1/1000
CR              EQU 0DH
LF              EQU 0AH
MSB             EQU 7
LSB             EQU 0
VTMR0           EQU -(FCLOCK/FINT)
ACK             EQU 6

;*************************************************
;       DEFINICAO DOS BITS EXTERNOS
;*************************************************

;PORT A

TX      EQU 0       ;TRANSMISSÃO SERIAL
RTS     EQU 1       ;CONTROLE RTS
CTS     EQU 2       ;CONTROLE CTS
S_ETIQ      EQU 3       ;SENSOR DE ETIQUETA PRESENTE
JUMPER      EQU 4       ;JUMPER PARA SELEÇÃO

;PORT B

RX      EQU 0       ;RECEPÇÃO SERIAL

PULS2       EQU 4       ;GERA PULSO PARA O MOTOR 2


;*************************************************
;       DEFINIÇÕES AUXILIARES
;*************************************************

#DEFINE _Z      STATUS,Z
#DEFINE _C      STATUS,C
#DEFINE BANCO0      BCF STATUS,RP0
#DEFINE BANCO1      BSF STATUS,RP0
#DEFINE PULSO2_1    BSF PORTB,PULS2
#DEFINE PULSO2_0    BCF PORTB,PULS2
#DEFINE TX_1        BSF PORTA,TX
#DEFINE TX_0        BCF PORTA,TX
#DEFINE RTS_1       BSF PORTA,RTS
#DEFINE RTS_0       BCF PORTA,RTS

;*************************************************
;       DEFINICAO DOS TEMPOS
;*************************************************

TMP1        EQU -.2     ;TEMPO DO SINAL EM 1 NA BUSCA DO ZERO
TMP2        EQU -.2     ;TEMPO DO SINAL EM 0 NA BUSCA DO ZERO
TMP3        EQU -.200   ;TEMPO PARA RECONHECER O JUMPER

TMP4        EQU -.255       ;DELAY P/ GERAR PULSO
TMP5        EQU -.255



;*************************************************
;       DEFINICAO DAS FLAGS
;*************************************************
;*** FLAGS

TZERO   EQU 0       ;INDICA QUE "CONT" CHEGOU A ZERO
RXMEN   EQU 1       ;INDICA MENSAGEM RECEBIDA
TZERO2  EQU 7       ;INDICA QUE DEVE BLOQUEAR

;*************************************************
;               AREA DE DADOS NA EEPROM
;*************************************************


    CBLOCK 0
E2INICIO    

    ENDC

;*************************************************
;               AREA DE DADOS
;*************************************************


    CBLOCK 0CH

;*** POSIÇÕES PARA SALVAR NA INTERRUPÇÃO

W_TEMP
STATUS_TEMP

;*** CONTADORES

CONT
CONT_CARAC
CONT_PULSO
CONT_PULSO1
CONT_RS
CONT_RTX
CONT_DELAY:2
CONT_ESTAB

;*** POSIÇÕES AUXILIARES DO MOVIMENTO

POS_ATUAL
PROX_CARAC
DESL_NCARAC

;*** FLAGS INDICATIVAS DE ESTADOS

FLAGS

;*** POSICOES PARA A COMUNICACAO SERIAL

TXBUF
TXRXDATA
RXPONT
RXBUFF:.10

    ENDC



;*************************************************
;               PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
;*************************************************

        ORG 0

RESET
        MOVLW IPORTA            ;VALORES INICIAIS DO PORTA
        MOVWF PORTA
        MOVLW IPORTB            ;VALORES INICIAIS DO PORTB
        GOTO CRESET

;*** INTERRUPÇÃO

RELOGIO
        MOVWF W_TEMP            ;SALVA POSICAO ATUAL DOS REGISTROS
        SWAPF STATUS,W
        BANCO0
        MOVWF STATUS_TEMP
RELOGIO0
    BTFSC INTCON,INTF
    GOTO RECEBE
    MOVLW VTMR0
    MOVWF TMR0
    BTFSC FLAGS,TZERO
    GOTO RELOGIO_FIM
    INCFSZ CONT,F
    GOTO RELOGIO_FIM
    BSF FLAGS,TZERO
RELOGIO_FIM 
    BCF INTCON,T0IF
RELOGIO_FIM1    
    SWAPF STATUS_TEMP,W
        MOVWF STATUS
        SWAPF W_TEMP,F
        SWAPF W_TEMP,W
        RETFIE                  ;RETORNA DA INTERRUPCAO


;**************************************
;*** ROTINAS DE COMUNICAÇÃO SERIAL  ***
;**************************************        

DELAY0
    CALL DELAY1
    CALL DELAY1
    CALL DELAY1
DELAY2
    CALL DELAY1
    RETURN
DELAY1
    MOVLW -.135
    MOVWF CONT_DELAY
DELAY
    INCFSZ CONT_DELAY,F
    GOTO DELAY
    RETLW .0

RECEBE
    CALL DELAY2
    MOVLW .8                ;RECEBE 8 BITS
    MOVWF CONT_RS
RX_PROX
    CALL DELAY0
    RRF TXRXDATA,F          ;RODA O BUFFER DE RECEPCAO
    BTFSS PORTB,RX
    BCF TXRXDATA,MSB
    BTFSC PORTB,RX
    BSF TXRXDATA,MSB
RX_PROX1
    DECFSZ CONT_RS,F    ;FICA NO LOOP ATE TERMINAR 
    GOTO RX_PROX
    MOVLW '*'
    XORWF TXRXDATA,W
    BTFSC _Z
    GOTO RX_PROX2
RX_FIM  
    BCF INTCON,INTF
    GOTO RELOGIO_FIM1

RX_PROX2        
    BSF PORTA,RTS
    BSF FLAGS,RXMEN
    GOTO RX_FIM

;*** TRANSMITE VIA RS-232

TRANSMITE
    BCF PORTA,TX        ;GERA O START DE TRANSMISSAO
        MOVLW .8                ;TRANSMITE 8 BITS
        MOVWF CONT_RTX
TX_PROX
    CALL DELAY0
    BTFSS TXBUF,LSB     ;TRANSFERE TXRXBUF.0 -> TX
    GOTO TX_PROX1
    BSF PORTA,TX
    GOTO TX_PROX2
TX_PROX1
    BCF PORTA,TX
TX_PROX2
    RRF TXBUF,F             ;RODA O BUFFER DE TRANSMISSAO
        DECFSZ CONT_RTX,F        ;FICA NO LOOP 8 VEZES
        GOTO TX_PROX
        CALL DELAY0
        BSF PORTA,TX            ;GERA 1 STOP
    CALL DELAY0
        RETLW .0


;********************************
;*** CONTINUA A INICIALIZAÇÃO ***
;********************************

CRESET
        MOVWF PORTB
        BANCO1
        MOVLW PPORTA            ;INICIALIZA BITS DO PORTA
        MOVWF TRISA
        MOVLW PPORTB            ;INICIALIZA BITS DO PORTB
        MOVWF TRISB
        MOVLW POPTION           ;PROGRAMA REGISTRO OPTION
        MOVWF OPTION_REG
        BANCO0
    MOVLW VTMR0     ;INICIALIZA TEMPORIZADOR
    MOVWF TMR0
    CLRF FLAGS      
    MOVLW PINTCON       
    MOVWF INTCON
    MOVLW .10
    MOVWF CONT_ESTAB
ESTAB2
    MOVLW TMP3
    MOVWF CONT
    BCF FLAGS,TZERO
ESTAB
    BTFSS FLAGS,TZERO
    GOTO ESTAB  
    DECFSZ CONT_ESTAB,F
    GOTO ESTAB2
    BANCO0


;*********************************************
;*** LOOP PRINCIPAL DE FUNCOES DO PROGRAMA ***
;*********************************************

PRINC
    BTFSS FLAGS,RXMEN   ;ESPERA MENSAGEM RECEBIDA
    GOTO PRINC
    BCF FLAGS,RXMEN

    CALL PROX_ETIQ      
    GOTO PRINC  

PROX_ETIQ
    MOVLW .200
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW .200
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW .128
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW .200
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW .200
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW .128
    CALL DESLOCA_POS
    MOVLW ACK
    MOVWF TXBUF
    CALL TRANSMITE
    RETURN


DESLOCA_POS
    MOVWF CONT_PULSO1
DESL_POS_0  
    PULSO2_1        ;PULSO EM 1
    MOVLW TMP4      ;TEMPO EM 1
    MOVWF CONT
DESL_POS_1  
    INCFSZ CONT,F
    GOTO DESL_POS_1     ;ESPERA CONTADOR
    MOVLW TMP4      ;TEMPO EM 1
    MOVWF CONT
DESL_POS_1A 
    INCFSZ CONT,F
    GOTO DESL_POS_1A    ;ESPERA CONTADOR


    PULSO2_0        ;PULSO EM 0
    MOVLW TMP5      ;TEMPO EM 0
    MOVWF CONT      ;DISPARA CONTADOR
DESL_POS_2
    INCFSZ CONT,F
    GOTO DESL_POS_2
    MOVLW TMP5      ;TEMPO EM 0
    MOVWF CONT      ;DISPARA CONTADOR
DESL_POS_2A
    INCFSZ CONT,F
    GOTO DESL_POS_2A


    DECFSZ CONT_PULSO1,F
    GOTO DESL_POS_0
    RETURN

        END
```

Comment: This isn't even in English.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the fact that comments are not in English is irrelevant to the question asked. He simply needs a delay routine for PIC16F84.

Comment: I would really recommend to hire local professional for this task. You didn't even describe what the step motor does, or how you plan to test it. If this operates for example some big machinery, some bug in new version may effectively hurt or kill somebody. And SO as I understand it is NOT "write a code for me" service. If you feel adventurous, you may try to find out how long `CALL DELAY0/1/2` are taking, and build 1s delay from them, but it looks to me all of them will be way too  fast (like milliseconds).

Comment: I made it work for a few times adding this code:

 cblock
 d1
 d2
 d3
 endc

   ;3999994 cycles
 movlw 0x23
 movwf d1
 movlw 0xB9
 movwf d2
 movlw 0x09
 movwf d3
Delay_0
 decfsz d1, f
 goto $+2
 decfsz d2, f
 goto $+2
 decfsz d3, f
 goto Delay_0

   ;6 cycles
 goto $+1
 goto $+1
 goto $+1

Answer (score 1):

My condolences.

It's been a long while since I programmed PICs, but this resource seems relevant:

http://www.nomad.ee/PIC/picprog.shtml

Under "TIMING", there is a delay routine that seems to be similar to your problem.

Alternatively, AFAIK there is a 'watchdog timer' in [PIC16F84A](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en010230) that you can use for more precise timing tasks.

In any case, you should take into consideration the frequency of the crystal you are using.

Comment: The crystal has "C R 16.000" written in it, this motor pulls the production line after another machine engraves the product, since the engraving is taking longer I need it to wait a little before pulling it.

Comment: A watchdog timer is to reset the device if it's not serviced quickly enough (i.e. the code has crashed). It should not be used for timing or delays.